How to write the return type of this method?
I am using laravel 11 + phpstan for the quality code.
In this method :
    /**
     * @param array<string> $request
     * @return LengthAwarePaginator<App\Models\User>
     */
    public function index(array $request)
    {
        $query = User::orderBy('name');

        $query->when(isset($request['status']), function ($q) use ($request) {
            return $q->where('status', $request['status']);
        });

        return $query->paginate(10);
}

I have this larastan error :
Method App\Repositories\UserRepository::index() should return
Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator<App\Repositories\App\Models\User> but returns
Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator<App\Models\User>.
I have the impression that I'm missing something in terms of paths or namespaces. But I can't get through it!
What could be my error ?

I found the solution which was so obvious.
I just written this :
* @return LengthAwarePaginator<User>

instead of this :
* @return LengthAwarePaginator<App\Models\User>

